# IFileProvider does not execute if a cshtml file already exists on disk

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing a `IFileProvider` with which I intend to load content from a database.  I have adapted this code below and as a proof-of-concept I'm just hard-coding a string if a particular request matches "contact".

On disk, I have a file, `contact.cshtml` in my Pages folder.  If I do *not* use my new `DatabaseFileProvider`, then the `contact.cshtml` page renders perfectly, as expected.

When I include the `IFileProvider` below, the request to the `contact.cshtml` page is indeed overridden - again, as expected.

However, if try to intercept a request for a cshtml file that does *not* exist, my code never actually gets hit.  You can see in my comments for example, that if I replace the work "contact" with "dynamic", it fails to execute.

I'm sure this is to do with how I've intertwined my `IFileProvider` with MVC's default `PhysicalFileProvider`.

Here is my setup:

```
public class DatabaseFileProvider : IFileProvider
    {
        
        public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
        {
            var result = new DatabaseFileInfo(subpath);
            return result.Exists ? result as IFileInfo : new NotFoundFileInfo(subpath);
        }
    }

public class DatabaseFileInfo : IFileInfo
    {
        private string _viewPath;
        private byte[] _viewContent;
        private DateTimeOffset _lastModified;
        private bool _exists = false;

        public DatabaseFileInfo(string viewPath)
        {
            _viewPath = viewPath;
            GetView(viewPath);
        }
        public bool Exists => _exists;

        public bool IsDirectory => false;

        public DateTimeOffset LastModified => _lastModified;

        public long Length
        {
            get
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(_viewContent))
                {
                    return stream.Length;
                }
            }
        }

        public string Name => Path.GetFileName(_viewPath);

        public string PhysicalPath => null;

        public Stream CreateReadStream()
        {
            return new MemoryStream(_viewContent);
        }

        private void GetView(string viewPath)
        {
            if (viewPath == null) return;
            if (viewPath.ToLower().IndexOf("_view") != -1) return;

            // PROBLEM: this only works if the file EXISTS on disk ???!!!  Try switching out "contact" (works) with "dynamic" (doesn't work)
            // Not even the breakpoint gets hit?

            if (viewPath.ToLower().ToLower().IndexOf("contact") == -1) return;

            var html = "This is NOT cshtml";

            _viewContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
            _lastModified = DateTime.Now;
            _exists = true;
        }
    }
```

...and in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            
            services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opts => {
                    opts.FileProviders.Clear();
                    opts.FileProviders.Add(new DatabaseFileProvider());
                    opts.FileProviders.Add(Environment.ContentRootFileProvider);

                    /*
                    opts.FileProviders.Clear();
                    opts.FileProviders.Add(new CompositeFileProvider(
                        Environment.ContentRootFileProvider,
                        new DatabaseFileProvider()
                    )); 
                    */
                }
            );
            
        }
```

As you can see, I've left in a second implementation using a `CompositeFileProvider`, but the issue remains.  I've also changed the order of providers around.

I'm sure I'm doing something silly - can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I eventually found the answer, which is to make sure you implement the `IFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents` method.  I had been ignoring this because I thought it was only to facilitate *directory browsing*, but it looks like .Net Core pre-queries all provider contents upon startup, and this method is used to tell it exactly what you've got.

Full source code attached below:

```
public class FoundationEmbeddedResourcesFileProvider : IFileProvider
    {

        private static readonly Assembly FoundationAssembly = typeof(Foundation.UI.Web.Core.Code.Library).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        private static readonly List<string> ResourceNames = FoundationAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames().ToList();
        private bool IsPartOfCompositeProvider { get; set; }


        public class FoundationEmbeddedResourceDirectory : IDirectoryContents
        {

            private IEnumerator<IFileInfo> Files { get; set; }

            public FoundationEmbeddedResourceDirectory(Assembly ass, string subPath)
            {
                var subFolderNames = new List<string>();
                var subFilePaths = new List<string>();

                foreach (var resource in ResourceNames) {
                    var filePath = ConvertResourceFormatToFilePath(resource); // e.g. /Pages/Foundation/Views/MainMenu.cshtml

                    // If this item is not in our directory, we break
                    if (!filePath.ToLower().StartsWith(subPath.ToLower())) continue;


                    var subFolders = filePath.Substring(subPath.Length).Split("/").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();

                    // Remove the 'file' component from the directories list
                    subFolders = subFolders.Take(subFolders.Count - 1).ToList();

                    // Direct directory?
                    if (subFolders.Count == 1) {
                        subFolderNames.Add(subFolders[0]);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Direct file?
                    if (subFolders.Count == 0) {
                        subFilePaths.Add(filePath);
                        continue;
                    }

                }

                var files = new List<IFileInfo>();
                files.AddRange(subFolderNames.Distinct().Select(x => new ResourceStreamResult(ass, x, true)));
                files.AddRange(subFilePaths.Distinct().Select(x => new ResourceStreamResult(ass, x, false)));

                // Add sub folders
                // if (subPath == "/Pages") files.Add(new ResourceStreamResult(ass, "Foundation/Views", true));

                this.Exists = files.Any();
                this.Files = files.GetEnumerator();
            }

            #region Implementation of IEnumerable

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public IEnumerator<IFileInfo> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this.Files;
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return GetEnumerator();
            }

            #endregion

            #region Implementation of IDirectoryContents

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public bool Exists { get; set; }

            #endregion
        }

        public class FoundationEmbeddedResourceChangeToken : IChangeToken
        {
            #region Implementation of IChangeToken

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public IDisposable RegisterChangeCallback(Action<object> callback, object state)
            {
                return null;
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public bool HasChanged
            {
                get { return true; }
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public bool ActiveChangeCallbacks
            {
                get { return false; }
            }

            #endregion
        }

        public class ResourceStreamResult : IFileInfo
        {
            #region Implementation of IFileInfo

            // private Assembly Assembly = null;
            private Stream Stream = null;
            private string ResourceName = "";

            public ResourceStreamResult(Assembly assembly, string filePath, bool isDirectory)
            {
                this.IsDirectory = isDirectory;
                // this.Assembly = assembly;
                this.PhysicalPath = filePath;
                this.ResourceName = ConvertFilePathToResourceFormat(filePath);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ResourceName)) this.Stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(this.ResourceName);
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public Stream CreateReadStream()
            {
                return this.Stream;
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public bool Exists
            {
                get {
                    if (this.IsDirectory) return IsDirectory;
                    return (this.Stream != null);
                }
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public long Length
            {
                get
                {
                    if (this.Stream == null) return 0;
                    return this.Stream.Length;
                }
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public string PhysicalPath { get; set; }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public string Name
            {
                get {
                    if (this.IsDirectory) return this.PhysicalPath;
                    return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(this.PhysicalPath);
                }
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public DateTimeOffset LastModified
            {
                get { return DateTime.UtcNow; }
            }

            /// <inheritdoc />
            public bool IsDirectory { get;set; }

            #endregion
        }

        public FoundationEmbeddedResourcesFileProvider(bool isPartOfCompositeProvider)
        {
            this.IsPartOfCompositeProvider = isPartOfCompositeProvider;
        }


        #region Implementation of IFileProvider

        public static string ConvertFilePathToResourceFormat(string filePath)
        {
            var s = filePath.Replace("/", ".");
            if (s.StartsWith(".")) s = s.Substring(1);

            // CSHTML files are prefixed with the /Pages root, but content files (.js etc) are not.  This makes sense because there are different providers for static files and content files
            // BUT, we source all our content files through the /Pages sub directory because we like to nest javascript/css alongside their views
            if (!s.StartsWith("Pages.")) s = "Pages." + s;

            // Prefix with assembly name
            s = "Foundation.UI.Web.Core." + s;

            // Resource names are case sensitive but the incoming request is not necessarily
            s = ResourceNames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToLower() == s.ToLower());

            return s;
        }

        public static string ConvertResourceFormatToFilePath(string resourceName)
        {
            var s = resourceName;
            s = s.Replace("Foundation.UI.Web.Core", "");

            s = s.Replace(".", "/");

            // Retain file extension
            var lastSlash = s.LastIndexOf("/");
            if (lastSlash != -1) s = s.Substring(0, lastSlash) + "." + s.Substring(lastSlash + 1);

            return s;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
        {
            var resource = new ResourceStreamResult(FoundationAssembly, subpath, false);

            if (!resource.Exists) {
                // Composite providers expect NULL in order to move on to the next item
                if (this.IsPartOfCompositeProvider) return null;
                return new NotFoundFileInfo(subpath);
            }
            return resource;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath)
        {
            return new FoundationEmbeddedResourceDirectory(FoundationAssembly, subpath);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IChangeToken Watch(string filter)
        {
            return new FoundationEmbeddedResourceChangeToken();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Would you share the `GetDirectoryContents` implementation?

Comment: Sure no problem I have amended the answered post.  It won't compile because I didn't include the dependencies, but you will hopefully get the idea.